# Circuitikz line and component color

Tags: circuitikz

I wish to make a component (capacitor) in my circuit a different color (blue).

When I use the code:

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw(0,0) to [C,l_=$C$,*-*,color=blue](0,2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This happens: [image]

But I want the lines going to the capacitor to be blue too and not black.
How do I do this if I wish to add additional components to my circuit later on and want those to be black?

Can I also make the label C blue too?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add the option `[blue]` to your `draw` command, everything should be fine. If you want to revert to the default color, you end the blue draw command with a semicolon and begin a new `draw` command without the blue color options.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw[blue] (0,0) to [C,l_=$C$,*-*,color=blue] (0,2);
    \draw (2,0) to [C,l_=$C$,*-*] (2,2);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: Capacitors]

Comment: Thanks, but what if I wish to add other items to my circuit that I do not want to be blue?

Comment: @Jenni, then you don't use the color options for subsequent `draw` commands. Example: `\draw[blue] <blue component>; \draw <standard, black component>;`