# How to color electrolytic capacitor in CircuiTikZ completely?

Tags: color, circuitikz

I can change the color of almost all components in *CircuiTikZ* using the method explained here: [Circuitikz line and component color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179044/circuitikz-line-and-component-color)

The following example shows my problem with the electrolytic capacitor, as the plus sign and the filling stays black:

```latex
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,european]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,2) to [diode] (0,0);
        \draw[blue] (1,2) to [diode, color=blue] (1,0);
        \draw (3,2) to [elko] (3,0);
        \draw[blue] (4,2) to [elko, color=blue] (4,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: Faulty coloring of electrolytic capacitor, but proper working for diode]

I added the example of a diode where coloring works properly to make the problem more clear.

Comment: The plus sign is probably implemented using \pgftext, which uses a different color than the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. The "black" is hardcoded in in a lot of places. 
It is probably a bug, and I should change it with the basic color... I'll look into it.

Meanwhile I can offer you a trick, redefining a better elko:

```latex
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,european]{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
%% Electrolytic Capacitor
\pgfcircdeclarebipolescaled{capacitors}
{}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ecapacitor/height}}
{ecapacitor}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ecapacitor/height}}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ecapacitor/width}}
{
    \pgfsetrectcap
    % % % Draw plus pole
    \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{bipoles}{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.4\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.4\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgf@circ@draworfill
    % % Draw minus pole
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.4\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.4\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfsetfillcolor{\ctikzvalof{color}}
    \pgfusepath{draw,fill}
    \pgfsetcolor{\ctikzvalof{color}}
    % % plus pole annotation
    \pgftext[right,at=\pgfpoint{1.2\pgf@circ@res@left}{.6\pgf@circ@res@up}]
    {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/ecapacitor/font} $+$}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,2) to [diode] (0,0);
        \draw[blue] (1,2) to [diode, color=blue] (1,0);
        \draw (3,2) to [elko] (3,0);
        \draw[color=blue] (4,2) to [elko, color=blue] (4,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PD It's not hardcoded in a lot of places... [I will fix it](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/289).

Or, alternatively,

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,european]{circuitikz}
\tikzset{ccolor/.code=\colorlet{black}{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,2) to [diode] (0,0);
        \draw (1,2) to [diode, ccolor=blue] (1,0);
        \draw (3,2) to [elko] (3,0);
        \draw (4,2) to [elko, ccolor=blue] (4,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, good to know that it will be fixed. Meanwhile I tried to use the workaround suggested. And I get the following 3 errors:

- Undefined control sequence: \pgfcircdeclarebipolescaled{capacitors}

- Missing number, treated as zero: \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{bipoles}{\pgfstartlinewidth}

-  Undefined control sequence: \pgf@circ@draworfill

Comment: Ah, ok. This is probably because my workaround is built on top of version 0.9.4. If you tell me your version I will post a version for you. Anyway, the trick is to copy the definition of `ecapacitor` from your `pgfcircbipoles.tex` and change the two words `black` into `\ctikzvalof{color} `.

Comment: Version 0.9.5 will have this bug fixed (it's in the `-git` version now). But you can use the nice @schrödingers-cat workaround for now.

Comment: Currently i am working with version 0.8.3, but the workaround works there anyway aswell!